# JavaFX Not populating data in tableColumn

Tags: java, javafx

So I am trying to make a simple JavaFX program that displays a few tables of data. I have my model view controller, and from what I can tell everything looks clear. Running the application shows no problems except that no data shows up in the tables. The 4 tables are initialized, I can click on them so clearly its setting them up, just no data is being put inside them. Here is my code.

```html
package releaseData;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Observable;

import releaseData.model.ReleaseData;
import releaseData.view.ShowReleaseDataController;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainApp extends Application {
 private Stage primaryStage;
 //must match the the type of pane in .fxml file
 private AnchorPane rootLayout;
 
 //set up a list 
 private ObservableList<ReleaseData> releaseData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

 //Constructor
 public MainApp()
 {
  releaseData.add(new ReleaseData("Borderlands", "2K", "11/24/2010", "4/5"));
  releaseData.add(new ReleaseData("Half-Life 2", "Valve", "9/9/2002", "5/5"));
  releaseData.add(new ReleaseData("Far Cry 3", "Activision", "12/1/2012", "5/5"));
  releaseData.add(new ReleaseData("Goat Simulator", "Coffe-Stain", "8/1/2014", "3/5"));
 }
 /**
 @return
 */
 public ObservableList<ReleaseData> getReleaseData()
 {
  return releaseData;
 }
 
 @Override
 public void start(Stage primaryStage)
 {
  this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
  this.primaryStage.setTitle("Game Data");
  initRootLayout();
 }
 
 public void initRootLayout() 
 {
  try {
   //Load fxml layout
   FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
   loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/releaseDataOverview.fxml"));
   rootLayout = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
   
   //Give the controller access
   ShowReleaseDataController controller = loader.getController();
   controller.setMainApp(this);
   
   //Show scene containing the root layout
   Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
   primaryStage.setScene(scene);
   primaryStage.show();
   
  }catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace(); }
 }
 
 public Stage getPrimaryStage()
 {
  return primaryStage;
 }
 
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  launch(args);
 }
}
```

```html
package releaseData.model;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class ReleaseData {
 
 private final StringProperty name;
 private final StringProperty publisher;
 private final StringProperty date;
 private final StringProperty rating;
 
 //Constructors
 public ReleaseData() { this(null, null, null, null); }
 
 public ReleaseData(String name, String publisher, String date, String rating){
  this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
  this.publisher = new SimpleStringProperty(publisher);
  this.date = new SimpleStringProperty(date);
  this.rating = new SimpleStringProperty(rating);
 }
 
 //Sets, gets, properties
 public String getName() { return name.get(); }
 public void setName(String name) {this.name.set(name); }
 public StringProperty nameProperty() { return name; }
 
 public String getPublisher() {return publisher.get(); }
 public void setPublisher(String publisher) {this.publisher.set(publisher); }
 public StringProperty publisherProperty() {return publisher; }
 
 public String getDate() { return date.get(); }
 public void setDate(String date) {this.date.set(date); }
 public StringProperty dateProperty() { return date; }
 
 public String getRating() { return rating.get(); }
 public void setRating(String rating) { this.rating.set(rating); }
 public StringProperty ratingProperty() {return rating; }
 
 }
```

```html
package releaseData.view;

import releaseData.MainApp;
import releaseData.model.ReleaseData;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;

public class ShowReleaseDataController {
 
 @FXML
 private TableView<ReleaseData> releaseDataTable;
 @FXML
 private TableColumn<ReleaseData, String> nameColumn;
 @FXML
 private TableColumn<ReleaseData, String> publisherColumn;
 @FXML 
 private TableColumn<ReleaseData, String> dateColumn;
 @FXML
 private TableColumn<ReleaseData, String> ratingColumn;
 
 private MainApp mainApp;
 
 public ShowReleaseDataController() {}
 
 
 @FXML
 private void initializer()
 {
  nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().nameProperty());
  publisherColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().publisherProperty());
  dateColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().dateProperty());
  ratingColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().ratingProperty());
 }
 
 public void setMainApp(MainApp mainApp)
 {
  this.mainApp=mainApp;
  releaseDataTable.setItems(mainApp.getReleaseData());
 }

}
```

I've done about everything I can think of to find the issue. If someone could point me in the right direction I would be extremely grateful!

Answer (score 0):

The initialisation method should be

```
public void initialize() {...}
```

not `initializer()`

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you! One stray letter had me completely stuck for a good 2 hours! I just needed somebody else to take a look at it for me! This is for a final tonight, you saved my bacon pal!